# How do I convert this OpenGL makefile from Linux to Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, makefile

I'm trying to compile a OpenGL program on my MacBook and can't figure out how to convert this makefile.

```
CFLAGS= -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS= -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lGL -lGLU -lm -lglut 

BINARIES=q2

all: $(BINARIES)

clean: 
 -rm *.o $(BINARIES)

q2 : q2.o 
 g++ $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o q2 

q2.o: q2.cpp 
 g++ -c $(CFLAGS) q2.cpp

depend:
 makedepend *.cpp
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting or other problems you are running into ?

Comment: The compiler can't find those libraries since their Linux specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the source code

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Don't include GL.h or GLU.h. glut.h should pull them for you regardless of the platform.

And change your Makefile

```
CFLAGS= 
LDFLAGS= -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa
```

Note that I was also able to build something using your original Makefile but I think that's because I have Apple X11 installed.

Comment: Yeah just realized that it would have compiled correctly if I fixed my typo in the includes :P. Thanks anyways though, this makes it run natively.